Inferencing ONNX model of pytorch's mask r-cnn never works
The problem: inferencing onnx model gives empty results or weirdly shaped results
What i'm trying: pytorch pretrained mask-rcnn -> finetune on dataset -> save as onnx -> inference on onnx-> plot results
Everything i currently have works until the inference.
my main.py file: https://pastebin.com/3jNfZdBi
getting info about my saved onnx model gives
Model Input Info:
Name: input
Shape: ['batch_size', 3, 'height', 'width']
Type: tensor(float)

Model Output Info:
Name: boxes
Shape: ['Concatboxes_dim_0', 4]
Type: tensor(float)
Name: labels
Shape: ['Gatherlabels_dim_0']
Type: tensor(int64)
Name: scores
Shape: ['Gatherlabels_dim_0']
Type: tensor(float)
Name: masks
Shape: ['Unsqueezemasks_dim_0', 'Unsqueezemasks_dim_1', 'Unsqueezemasks_dim_2', 'Unsqueezemasks_dim_3']
Type: tensor(float)

My code for inferencing: https://pastebin.com/wxvp649G
I suspect i either: save things wrongly to onnx OR don't preprocess my data correctly OR my inferencing code is wrong (or something other i dont know about)
Code for saving to onnx
def save_model_onnx(models_file_path, model, torch_input):
    # Traditional export method. There is also an experimental dynamo_export method
    torch.onnx.export(
        model.cpu(),
        torch_input.cpu(),
        models_file_path, #full path to the model including the model itself i.e. ./models/model.onnx
        export_params = True,
        opset_version=15,  # Choose a supported ONNX opset version
        do_constant_folding=True,  # Fold constant nodes for optimization
        input_names = ['input'],
        output_names = ['boxes', 'labels', 'scores', 'masks'],
        dynamic_axes={
        "input": {0: "batch_size", 2: "height", 3: "width"},  
        }
    )
    logging.info(f"Model saved at {models_file_path}")


Are you sure that you only need to normalize the images by dividing using 255 (as shown in your code)? Usually, mean and stdev values are calculated across all images of the training set and used to normalize the images ((x-u)/sigma). I would check if you are missing that pre-processing step.
